# Getting error "The operation has timed out." when my procedure send around 5000 emails

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure which identifies number of employees and send email to them dynamically (add names in TO / from).
Out of 5000 emails triggered only 700-800 gets sent other are in re-trying or failed status every time.

getting below error :

> The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure.
>    (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2017-04-14T12:40:47). 
>    Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The operation has timed out.).
>   ) 
>   The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2017-04-13T16:43:32). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Service not available, closing transmission channel.The server response was: 4.3.2 The maximum number of concurrent connections has exceeded a limit, closing transmission channel).

Comment: Are you using SQL Server DB Mail to send e-mails?

Comment: The error is clear `The server response was: 4.3.2 The maximum number of concurrent connections has exceeded a limit, closing transmission channel)` ,try inserting all the employee names into a table and send them in batches

Comment: Yes using sql server DB for EMAILs...  We are using WHILE loop for sending emails..  we tried sending in batches of 100 employees but no success also we also tried to put delay of 2 seconds but still no luck